# Сервер для java

Tags: java, сервер, клиент-сервер

Для небольших приложений на java, для самых примитивных задач, есть необходимость в сервере, с последующим подключением к нему пользователей (не очень много). Что проще/дешевле использовать, взять в аренду статический ip и использовать свой пк для этих целей, или взять в аренду уже некий сервер на котором запустить программу java сервера. Если второй вариант, то в какую сторону смотреть?

Comment: я не понимаю чем вам нравится java?

Comment: @Lofectr. причем тут нравится - не нравится. она есть, работает, занимает огромный сегмент рынка в определеннах классах задач, не задумывались почему так?

Comment: по теме - посмотрите в сторону paas(platform as service) такие как openshift, heroku, azure. на первом 2 года назад простенький конфиг на попробовать давали бесплатно. так же можно частенько обойтись serverless приложениями, все зависит от задачи.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Ору, как можно писать на языке, которые тебе не нравится? тем более это не оптимизированное говно

Comment: @Lofectr. да, возможно, однако бизнесу нужна скорость выкатывания фич, низкая стоимость поддержки, тестируемость, предсказуемость сроков реализации, низкой порог вхождения, а не работа на 20 процентов быстрее или оптмизированность кода.

Comment: чем C++ тогда сложнее java? проктически ничем

Comment: Или же python чем не подходит?